# Mysql, clean up loose ends

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there some nice automated way/program for cleaning up my database? I have a couple of tables with relations that in some cases just point at records that doesn't exist.

Comment: use a proper relational schema and cascade on foreign key attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing some [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).
Depending on the `ON DELETE` option, orphaned records will be deleted together with the referenced records, referencing columns set to `NULL`, or deleting will be rejected.

You will have to delete those existing entries manually using a query like this, before creating your constraints:

```
DELETE FROM table_a
WHERE ref_b IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table_b WHERE table_b.id = table_a.ref_b )
```